# PHP5- Preg_Match() Error

Tags: php, html

I realize there are other q's on this error, but I cannot read PHP for the life of me.

Error:
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Empty regular expression in /srv/disk11/1731569/www/straightpathbible.dx.am/prayer.php on line 87

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Empty regular expression in /srv/disk11/1731569/www/straightpathbible.dx.am/prayer.php on line 87

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/local/bin/sendmail -oi -t' in /srv/disk11/1731569/www/straightpathbible.dx.am/prayer.php on line 88

My site (for reference):
http://straightpathbible.dx.am/prayer.php

Code:

```
     if (email_is_valid($youremail) && !preg_match("\r",$youremail) && !preg_match("\n",$youremail) && $yourname != "" && $yourmessage != "" &&          substr(md5($user_answer),5,10) === $answer) {
     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $yourname = '';
    $youremail = '';
    $yourmessage = '';
    echo '<p style="color: blue;">'.$contact_submitted.'</p>'; }
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks for looking!

Comment: As per [**the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )` - `\r` and `\n` are not strings/regular expressions. What are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a warning because a regular expression should have delimiters, i.e. `"/\r/"` instead of just `"\r"`.

That said, use [`strpbrk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) instead:

```
if (email_is_valid($youremail) && strpbrk($youremail, "\r\n") === false ...
```

Then again, shouldn't `email_is_valid()` also catch that? Haven't heard of a valid email address containing newlines.

Comment: Thanks- let me try this out as soon as my host gets back online. The code was provided from a template so it's not my work.

Comment: Awesome, so I changed the if to look like this:
if (email_is_valid($youremail) && !preg_match("/\r/",$youremail) && !preg_match("/\n/",$youremail) && $yourname != "" && ....

And it works! Thanks SOOO much!! :)